# Bootstrap card "sub-classes" like card-title not working

Tags: css, blazor, bootstrap-5, blazor-webassembly, blazorstrap

I'm trying to shoe-horn BlazorStrap into an existing .net6 Blazor web assembly app. I think I have a problem with BootStrap that I need to fix before I can expect BlazorStrap to work correctly though.

Trying to narrow it down to one example:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The card has a border and a shadow but nothing inside the card seems to be styled.

[image: styles missing]

Can anyone help?

[the source is here](https://github.com/rhenry74/TechStore/tree/bootstrap-problems)

[run it here](https://salmon-dune-00ffa260f-4.eastus2.4.azurestaticapps.net/BlazorStrapTest)

Expected (from bootstrap example):

[image: expected look from bootstrap example site]

Comment: Change your path in `Index.html` from `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` to `lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Yes! Brian Parker rocks!

Answer (score 0):

I had an incorrect path to the bootstrap css

[code change](https://github.com/rhenry74/TechStore/commit/0a0ed80c258956d21b9e7cdeb2f5689af3a356da)